# How to print out the sum of each row of an array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array and I need to display the sum of each row. I have try to use transpose() but it does not work.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array((np.arange(0,10),
    np.arange(10,20),
    np.arange(20,30),
    np.arange(30,40)))
d = a.sum(axis=1)
print(a.transpose())
print(d)
```

My output is [ 45 145 245 345], [ 45 145 245 345] but I need to display as Row 1 sum is 45, Row 2 sum is 145, Row 3 sum is 245, Row 4 sum is 345

Comment: Is this a HW question?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you're already correctly summing up each row and you just need help displaying those sums succinctly. If this is the case this should solve your problem:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((np.arange(0,10),
    np.arange(10,20),
    np.arange(20,30),
    np.arange(30,40)))

d = a.sum(axis=1)

for e,i in enumerate(d):
    print('Row {} - sum: {}'.format(e+1,i))
```

Which prints:

> Row 1 - sum: 45

> Row 2 - sum: 145

> Row 3 - sum: 245

> Row 4 - sum: 345

if you don't want to use enumerate as you've stated, an alternative could be to run the loop like this:

```
for i,j in zip(d, range(len(d))):
    print('Row {} - sum: {}'.format(j+1,i))
```

In this code zip allows you through loop through two lists at once, where j will loop through the values 0 -> length of 'd'.
If your unsure about using zip you can always just do it simply like this:

```
for i range(len(d)):
    print('Row {} - sum: {}'.format(i+1,d[i]))
```

Let me know if this is what your after or if you'd like me to edit this code snippet to include something else.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Is there other method to solve it as I have yet to learn enumerate()

Comment: @unleasehed I've edited my answer to show a different method, let me know if this suffices.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(40).reshape(4,10)

for i, total in enumerate(a.sum(1)):
    print(f"Row {i+1} sum is {total}")
```

Edit: after reading about your lack of understanding of `enumerate`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(40).reshape(4,10)

totals = a.sum(1)
for i in range(totals.shape[0]):
    print(f"Row {i+1} sum is {totals[i]}")
```

`enumerate` is just a convenient way to get an index if you want to use a for each loop